# RazorEngine - Windows 10 Anniversary update 1607 - Could not load file or assembly System.Web.Razor

Tags: c#, windows-10, razorengine

I am using RazorEngine in one of our applications and it was working fine until Windows 10 Anniversary.  On machines with this update, RazorEngine stopped working and I am stuck with this error:   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Has anyone here encountered this?

Note:  This question is also posted here:  https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/450

Answer (score 1):

One thing that comes to mind that may help is that if the 'System.Web.Razor' assembly was being read from the GAC rather than being copied directly to the bin folder of your application when built and for some reason the Windows 10 Anniversary update removes / updates this assembly from the GAC it could cause this issue.

Comment: nice, even if it not the answer

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. There are 2 different RazorEngine.dll files included with the package, one for 4.0 and one for 4.5. They are identical in size and report the same version number. I inadvertently copied the one for 4.0 which was looking from the older System.Web.Razor DLL version.